# Is there a method to include both the blog author and editor in the blog's metadata?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

On one of my blogs, I am accepting guest contributions and would like to include them with a guest author byline. Additionally, I'd like to feature the profiles of our editorial team members who review and approve the content before it gets published.

Is there a method or plugin that can help showcase both author profiles in the blog metadata?

Appriciation in advance